# Android Flip Animation between Activity and Activity Group

Tags: android

I have an Activity with some buttons. On click of Button,Next Screen is displayed. The new Screen is displayed on a TabHost. I want to apply Flip Screen Transition between current Activity and the TabActivity.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

You could use the overridePendingTransition().
The transition animations can be defined in XML.